# How to get all page posts for a multilingual Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, stream, locale, feed

With the FB API I can only retrieve the stream for the country I'm registered (France) I would like to get ALL the posts even if they're not in French.

For example : http://www.facebook.com/Nina

I tried to put a "locale" parameter but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have an answer to this, please tell me i have the same problem here ...